# Programmatically change the UIImageView displaying image1 to image2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiimageview

The UIImageView is placed in interface builder.
I already created an IBOutlet. 
How do i programmatically change the UIImageView to view another image.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If myImageView is your outlet, then in code, you can use:

```
myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"myNewImage.png"];
```

Comment: Thank you very much
this is exactly what i was looking for
this works 100%.